Overlaying a line plot over a stacked bar plot with dual y axis
I tried many times to plot line data of temperature over a stacked bar chart, but it didn’t work. My data consists of four columns as shown below: site, Frequency, Movie _Status, and temperature:



Site
Freq
Moving _status
Temp




Site_1
34.
Totally_Moved.
30


Site_2
45.
Partially_Moved
29


Site_3
55.
Totally_Moved
29.5



Here is my code to generate the plot.
read.csv("Moving_site.csv")
Recovery_Status <- factor(sample(c("Totally_Moved", "Partially_Moved"),
                                 size = 50, replace = TRUE),
                          levels = c("Totally_Moved", "Partially_Moved")))

Frequency <- sample(0:100, size = 50, replace = TRUE)
Mean_Temp <- sample(0:50, size = 50, replace = TRUE)
Site <- c("Site_1”, “Site_2”, “Site_3”)

data<-read.table(file="Moving _site.txt", header=T)
data
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Site, y=Frequency, fill=Moving _Status)) + geom_bar(stat ="identity")

ggplot(data, aes(fill=Moving _Status, y=Frequency, x=Site)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")  + scale_fill_grey() + scale_y_continuous() +
  ggtitle("Movement")+ 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +  
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(color = 2,
                                  linewidth = 2))


I want to add another y axis to represent the temperature. I tried to add temperature data as a line plot over the stacked bar chart I made already, but it doesn't show up. How can I add a line plot of temperature over the bar chart?


What do you want on the x-axis for the temperatures? If you use Site, you will have a vertical line for each site.... Have your tried plotting the line you want without the column chart? Perhaps if you clarify I can help.

In ggplot2, you can add a secondary axis but it is more involved than in Excel, for instance. It's more of a decoration, in that you still need to map your data to the primary axis scale. So if you have temperatures from 25 to 35, but you want then mapped onto 0-1, you'd say geom_line(aes(y  = (Temp - 25)/10)) and specify scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = ~ (.*10)+25). https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html

There are a variety of related questions about secondary plots in ggplot2, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/3099219/6851825

I got the scale already but I got this message: ale_y_continuous (sec.axis = m
linewidth = 2)) + geom_line(aes (data = (Mean_Temp - 25)/10))
(. *10) +25)
Scale for y is already present.
Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale. geom_line(): Each group consists of only one observation. i Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
Warning message:
T
In geom_line(aes (data = (Mean_Temp



/10))
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: data because the scale needs to be rescaling




Here's an example with some faked data:
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  Recovery_Status = sample(
    c("Totally_Moved", "Partially_Moved"), 
    size = 50, replace = TRUE),
  Frequency = sample(0:100, size = 50, replace = TRUE),
  Site = sample(
    c("Site_1", "Site_2", 
      "Site_3"), 
    size = 50, replace = TRUE)
  )

temps <- data.frame(
  Site = c(“Site_1”, “Site_2”, “Site_3”),
  Mean_Temp = sample(16:32, size = 7, replace = TRUE)
  )

data <- left_join(data, temps, by = "Site")

ggplot(data, aes(x = Site)) + 
  geom_bar(
    aes(fill = Moving_Status, y = Frequency), 
    position = "fill", stat = "identity"
    )  + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(
      ~ . * 50, 
      name = "Mean_Temp", 
      labels = scales::label_number(suffix = "ºC")
      )
  ) +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  geom_line(
    data = data %>% 
      mutate(
        temp_norm = scales::rescale(
          Mean_Temp, from = c(0,50), to = c(0, 1))
        ),
    aes(y = temp_norm, group = 1),
    color = "red3", linewidth = 1
  ) +
  ggtitle("Movement")+ 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +  
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(color = 2, linewidth = 2))


Thank you so much, it worked finally, I just follow your codes, I appreciate your help
